# How to use regular expressions on a .html file in python?

Tags: python, html, regex

I'm very new to programming and I would really appreciate any help! I am trying to write
this little python script:

I have an `.html` file of a legal codification in §§. (For example: http://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/stgb/BJNR001270871.html) Now I want to write a python 
regex script to automatically tag specific §§. The relevant html code of the document is:

```
"<div class="jnnorm" id="BJNR398310001BJNE000100305" title="Einzelnorm"><div 

class="jnheader"> <a name="BJNR398310001BJNE000100305"/><a 

href="index.html#BJNR398310001BJNE000100305">Nichtamtliches    Inhaltsverzeichnis</a>h3><span 

class="jnenbez">&#167; 1</span>&#160;<span class="jnentitel"></span></h3> </div>"
```

Here `"div class="jnnorm"` should become `"div class="jnnorm MYTAGHERE"`. The last element in `"class="jnenbez">&#167; 1"` contains the number of the §, here § 1.

I am trying (and failing) to write a script that does the following:

1) Lets say I have a dictionary `my_dict = [112, 204]`

2) Find `"<span class="jnenbez">&#167; 112"` and `"<span class="jnenbez">&#167; 204"` in the `.htm` file

3) Go left from `"jnenbez">&#167; 112"` to the next `"jnnorm"` string and replace it with 
`"jnnorm MYTAGHERE"`.

Here is what I got so far, but I hit a roadblock quite soon.

```
f = file("filename.htm","r")
text = f.read()
import re
my_dict=[1,123,200]
# dont know how to find the §   
re.sub("jnnorm", "jnnorm MYTAGHERE", text)
#re.sub does not seem to work?
```

Comment: I always like opportunities to link to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454 Have you considered using a HTML parser like [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)?

Comment: Or lxml? BeautifulSoup's latest version is old, although it does the job and a new version is along the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`re.sub` doesn't change the string, it returns a new (modified) string instead. If you want the `text` variable to change you should assign the new value to it:

```
text = re.sub("jnnorm", "jnnorm MYTAGHERE", text)
```

Or simpler (given that regular expressions seem to be overdimensioned for a simple string replace):

```
text = text.replace("jnnorm", "jnnorm MYTAGHERE")
```

But for anything more complicated - yes, you should consider using a proper HTML parser.

Comment: Strings are immutable, so it's a given it doesn't change the string.

Answer (score 0):

using `BeautifulSoup`, retrieve `class` attribute's value.

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup     
findAll('class')
```

will return list of values of attributes 'class'.

ex.
with this doc

```
doc = ['<html><head><title>Page title</title></head>',
       '<body><p id="firstpara" align="center">This is paragraph <b>one</b>.',
       '<p id="secondpara" align="blah">This is paragraph <b>two</b>.',
       '</html>']
soup = BeautifulSoup(''.join(doc))
soup.findAll('b')
```

gives

```
# [<b>one</b>, <b>two</b>]
```

then, use regex or simply test if element in your list is in one of the element of the list.

this answers 1. and 2. from your question.